# Creating a manual link between 2 selected nodes in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add d3 nodes and links manually in D3 SVG - [codepen](https://codepen.io/aa1024/pen/NBxxLR?editors=1010)

I first enter the node name in `Node Name` text box and press the `Add N` button. IT adds the nodes to 2 select boxes `source` and `target`. After adding multiple nodes, I select an src node and target node and then click the `Add L` button to create a D3 link between them.

the add Node function is create a node on the SVG. However, I am facing issues while adding the link.

```
function addLink() {
 var x = document.getElementById("srcNodes");
 var y = document.getElementById("targetNodes");
 var link = document.createElement("option");
 var l = document.getElementById("linkedNodes");
 var idSrc = x.value , idTarget =y.value;
 link.text = idSrc + "<->" + idTarget;
 l.add(link);
 addLinkCanvas(idSrc,idTarget)
}


function addLinkCanvas(idSrc,idTarget){
  var nSrc,nTarget;
  alert (idSrc);
  nodes.forEach(function(idSrc) {if(node.id=== idSrc) { nSrc =node;} });
  nodes.forEach(function(idTarget){if(node.id=== idTarget){nTarget=node;}});
  links.push({         source: nSrc,         target: nTarget        });
  restart();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, it's just you were setting the 'nSrc' and 'nTarget' variables to the 'node' variable at the top of your .js file. Here's a fix (I also made it so that you can't create a link between nodes of the same id):

```
function addLinkCanvas(idSrc,idTarget){
  if (idSrc != idTarget) {
    var source = {},
        target = {};
    nodes.forEach(function (curNode) {
      if (typeof curNode.id != 'undefined') {
        if (curNode.id == idSrc)  {
          source = curNode;
        }
        if (curNode.id == idTarget) {
          target = curNode;
        }
      }
    });

    links.push({
      source: source,
      target: target
    });
    restart();
  }
}
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBVzWo?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. It was in my list to not add the link to itself :)

Comment: No problem, it looks like an interesting project. Good luck with the rest of your project :).